# Easiest way to implement this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an excel function: =Max(0, -Min(A1-B1, C1-B1))

and A1,B1,C1 are the Value column in the table:

Date, Key, Value

assume for now the Date is irrelevant and the Key is A,B,C for A1,B1,C1

How do I implement this excel function? The way I originally did it I had two joins (to get the values all in separate columns on the same row) but this seemed like overkill and there must be a smarter way?

Comment: And, what's wrong with the two joins solution?

Comment: I am going to need to add some selection criteria (via another join) for each of those joins, i will end up with about 5 joins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably reduce it to one join, since you only need `B` for the `A` part:

```
select  case 
        when min(Value - isnull(yt2.Value,0)) > 0 then 0
        else -min(Value - isnull(yt2.Value,0))
        end
from    YourTable yt1
join    YourTable yt2
on      yt1.Key = 'A' and yt2.key = 'B'
        or
        yt1.Key = 'B' and yt2.key = 'C'
```

Comment: Im really sorry I just noticed I forgot the minus symbol from C1-B1

Comment: @Porcupine: Answer edited, but now it's worse than two joins :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is suggesting a separate value for each row.  If so, then this is the query:

```
select t.*
       (case when -leastval < 0 then 0
             else -lesatval
        end) as TheValue
    end
from (select t.*,
             (case when A1 - B1 < C1 and A1 - B2 < B1 then A1 - B1
                   when C1 < B1 then C1
                   else B1
              end) as leastval
      from table t
     ) t
```

Now that I read the question right, let me assume that there is one value of A, B, and C per date.  Then you would use a variation on the above, by simply denomalizing the data first:

```
select t.*
       (case when -leastval < 0 then 0
             else -leastval 
        end) as TheValue
    end
from (select t.*,
             (case when A - B < C and A - B < B then A - B
                   when C < B then C
                   else B
              end) as leastval
      from (select date, 
                   min(case when key = 'A' then value end) as A,
                   min(case when key = 'B' then value end) as B,
                   min(case when key = 'C' then value end) as C
            from table t
            group by date
           ) t
     ) t
```

There are other ways to formulate this.  I tried to stay reasonably close to the Excel formulation.

By the way, some other databases offer Greatest() and Least() functions which may such a formula much easier to create.

Comment: But the table doesn't contain columns `A1`, `B1`, `C1`; it has a column called `Value` and a `Key` containing `A, B, C`.